# How to install Oracle SQL Developer on Linux (Pop!_OS)

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to install SQL Developer on my laptop. I've download the file from Oracle and follow the instruction, I have RPM installed, but when I run `rpm -Uhv sqldeveloper-21.4.3-063.0100.noarch.rpm`, I encountered the following:

```
rpm: RPM should not be used directly install RPM packages, use Alien instead!
rpm: However assuming you know what you are doing...
warning: RPM v3 packages are deprecated: sqldeveloper-21.4.3-063.0100.noarch
error: Failed dependencies:
    /bin/sh is needed by sqldeveloper-21.4.3-063.0100.noarch
```

What can I try next?

Comment: It sounds like you probably need to either a) learn more about Linux (non-trivial), or b) find a different ("better") Linux distro than Pop!_OS.  SUGGESTION: Debian variants (like Ubuntu and, it sounds like, Pop!_OS) natively use the "dkpg/yum" package manager.  Redhat variants (like Centos or Fedora) use RPM.  I'd encourage you to try one of the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to run a package made for redhat based systems, but PopOS is debian based.
To proceed with the installation you must first install rpm2cpio, then you can extract it by running the command "`# rpm2cpio datamodeler-21.4.2.059.0838-1.noarch.rpm`", then you can access the extracted directory.
Then you can use the command "`# ./sqldeveloper.sh`" to run the application.

But, ensure you have a JDK installed You will be prompted to enter a jdk path. (ie usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181) SQL Developer will automatically launch once jdk location is provided

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After a few more reading and discovering, I finally got to install it. I ended up installed it using deb package instead of rpm since it is way easier